# Matplotlib Graph Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, graphing

What i'm trying to do:

while inside a for loop, append to a list. If a requirement is met in that loop, append to another, then graph it. how do I do this:

Graphing code:

```
style.use("ggplot")
plt.plot(attempts, score)
plt.show()
```

When I use two normal lists it doesn't work. I tried numpy arrays but got:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

Using lists like:

```
np.append(score, acc, axis=None)
```

What code will work?

Comment: It's difficult to be certain, but your error suggests that one of your arrays is empty. It would help if you provided a lot more information about your problem, such as what `attempts` and `score` look like

Comment: The error indicate that `score` is a single scalar while `attempts` is a list.

Comment: @Andrew, I was able to fix the error at the bottom, but the graph is still empty.